# How to reject/close specific incoming number

Tags: android, phone-call

In my application I want to block the specific incoming number.I do google,and following [Blocking Incoming call - Android](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html). But this code is not working for me.I am testing on **android 2.3.5**

Here I have no activity class. >> First class is extends BroadcastReceiver.

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.blocknumber"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String blockedNumbers[] = { "xxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx" };
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    /*
     * String incommingNumber = b
     * .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
     */
    String incommingNumber = b.getString("incoming_number");
    Log.e("Incomming number========>", incommingNumber);
    // String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    for (int i = 0; i < blockedNumbers.length; i++) {
        Log.e("Incomming >>>>>>>>>>>>>========>", "" + i);
        if (incommingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(blockedNumbers[i])) {
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            try {
                Class<?> c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m
                        .invoke(telephony);
                // telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                telephonyService.endCall();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

ITelephony

```
public interface ITelephony {

    boolean endCall();

    void answerRingingCall();

    //void silenceRinger();

}
```

Comment: Your rep suggests you've been around SO more than long enough to know that your question is incomplete and that simply asking readers to review your code without knowing what problem they are looking for ("it doesn't work" is not sufficient) is frowned upon strongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, solve the issue,
Create IDL interface for getting core Telephony service
package name must be **com.android.internal.telephony**

FileName : `ITelephony.aidl`   // First Here I am createing `ITelephony.java`

For the create **.aidl** file `New > File` and write `ITelephony.aidl`

And follow the steps [Blocking a call without user intervention in android with an example.](http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/blocking-a-call-without-user-intervention-in-android/#comments)