# Block incoming call instantly in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my application I want to put a feature for blocking incoming calls.

For this I refereed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363534/how-to-reject-close-specific-incoming-number-android)

And its work perfectly but it takes nearly 2 seconds to end the call not instantly.

And at caller side a tune of **The person your calling busy at the movement** gets listen.

Is it possible to end the call without ringing?

Comment: maybe link of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17379800/1275574) answer is useful!

Comment: Thank you but i already refereed this link

Comment: i am facing the same problem, and i tried each and everything that i can find it on internet. I think this can only be done at root level. I dont know how. If some one can please tell me how. I be very thankful to you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this in your code.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    setResultData(null); //It will terminate the call
    Toast.makeText(context, "Call Terminated" + number, 5000).show();
}
```