# auto reject is not working,Now,how to automatically unregister the broadcast receiver

Tags: android

hello i am creating three different type of modules for mobile where the user can choose any of them by clicking a button.Now each module has its set of option to accept or reject calls.When for a particular module user selects reject then i am storing a Boolean value in database.
I want that whenever an user has selected call reject and checking out of that module to select another module then that call reject functionality should automatically stop.

`Now,how to automatically unregister the broadcast receiver` that rejects call.

```
  CallBlocker = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            //Java Reflections
            Class c = null;
            try {
                c = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Method m = null;
            try {
                m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            m.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephonyManager);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            telephonyManager.listen(callBlockListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        }//onReceive()

        PhoneStateListener callBlockListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    if (autoreject==1) {
                        try {
                            telephonyService.endCall();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }else {

                        unregisterReceiver(CallBlocker);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    };/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you out:-
[How to reject/close specific incoming number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363534/how-to-reject-close-specific-incoming-number)
[How to reject a call programatically android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393654/how-to-reject-a-call-programatically-android)
https://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/blocking-a-call-without-user-intervention-in-android/#comments